# add class to html elements with gulp

Tags: gulp

In my code, after the page loads I am using jQuery to add css classes to certain elements like so:

```
//add form-control to all text inputs
$( "input[type='text']" ).addClass( "form-control" );

//add btn btn-primary to all buttons in question class
$( ".question input[type=button]" ).addClass( "btn btn-primary" );
```

Is there any way of doing this in gulp so I do not need to do it every time the page loads?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this cause a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)? Why can't you add these in the markup? Or use SCSS/LESS to @extend the .form-control class to all your text boxes

Comment: @Barryman9000 yes it does cause FOUC which is why I'd like to do it in gulp. But actually you're right, I can do it in SASS/LESS too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write those styles in the HTML because I find it easier to read or debug later but you could also just use SASS to extend those bootstrap classes:

```
input[type=text] {
   @extend .form-control;
}

.question input[type=button] {
   @extend .btn;
   @extend .btn-primary;
}
```